# How to handle unassigned variables with R str_interp or str_glue

Tags: r, na, missing-data, stringr, string-interpolation

I have a template system for generating rmarkdown notebooks. I ran into a case where I have a slot for a variable that may or may not exist. There is no problem having the notebook handle having no value for what goes in the slot (it puts it into a vector and checks for empty).

But both `str_interp` and `str_glue` fail if the variable for the template slot is *not defined at all* in the parent environment. Neither `str_interp` nor `str_glue` seem to have a switch to handle this case.

With the nature of my templates, it would be extremely inconvenient to check for the existence or nonexistence of every variable for every slot at the time I do the interpolation.

```r
library(stringr)
a = 10
str_interp("hello ${a}")
#> [1] "hello 10"
str_interp("hello ${b}")
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): object 'b' not found
str_glue("hello {a}")
#> hello 10
str_glue("hello {b}")
#> Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir): object 'b' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Edit:

This is what I would like to see:

```r
a = 10
str_interp("hello ${a}") #==> "hello 10"
str_interp("hello ${b}", na_action="warn") #==> "hello " as well as warning
str_interp("hello ${b}", na_action="ignore") #==> "hello "
```

Comment: So I am assuming you don't want to perform checks like `if (exists('b'))` then `str_glue` ?

Comment: Right. I have a template with maybe a dozen or more "slots" such as `${stuff}`, and they may be different for teach template. However each template is interpolated in a context where the required variables are defined. Until I ran into this instance where I'd like to be able to handle some variables not being assigned.

Comment: What would you have to happen when a variable isn't defined?

Comment: @EmilHvitfeldt -- good point. Edited question.

Comment: If there is no available solution probably, you can write your own custom function as per your requirement.

Comment: @RonakShah I was assuming that I would have to write every single piece of code I ever use, starting with the R language itself. But then I would run into the problem that someone else who does not have my custom function would not be able to run my code. Oh, well. I'm back to using packages and libraries like other mortals.

Comment: Your other option would be to write your “better” function, send it to the package maintainer, and perhaps it will show up in a subsequent version.